# How to disable line width in OpenGL

Tags: ios, objective-c, opengl-es, line

I use `glLineWidth(widthLine);` to set line width, but I can't disable it effect to other lines.
I try using:

```
glLineWidth(0);
```

and:

```
glDisable(GL_LINE_WIDTH);
```

but don't working.

Ps: Its working, I use:

```
glLineWidth(1);
```

Comment: What are you trying to draw? I'm pretty sure that line width only applies to line primitives, which can't be drawn without a width.

Comment: That is a good way to generate `GL_INVALID_ENUM`, not much else.